# Get facebook news feed where type is Video

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to fetch a user's news feed posts where the post type is video.

I am using this (if you have a better way feel free to share):

```
<script>
FB.api('/me/home/', {limit: 1000}, function(response)
{
    response.data.forEach(function(object)
    {
        if (object.type == 'video')
        {
            console.log(object.message);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm not a experienced programmer and I need some tips about the right approach to do this efficiently.

The use case is that a user connects to my website using a facebook account, then I fetch the user's news feed like I showed above.

I want to store this info about the posts where the type is video in MongoDB, so here is my real question: to keep showing the oldest posts, I need to store the post's ID in my DB, right? So should I create a field called "fb_video_id" in the user info in the DB, or does this not work, or is it not the best way? (If you can show me some code examples, that is great.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL to grab stream posts that are only type video; read the documentation on [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and the [stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) and [stream_filter](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/) tables.

Depending on exactly what you want to achieve, it may be necessary to store the post_ids returned to you for querying in the future, or even more data if you don't want to be asking Facebook for potentially thousands of posts to show historical data. Given a little bit more information about what you are trying to achieve I'm sure I can help you more.

Comment: what i want to achieve is: posts_id,title,embed check for example this website alpha.shelby.tv, they fetch facebook videos and show on their platform basically is what i want to do. i have checked the code and seems that they fetch only the posts_id but now clear at all

Comment: Well, if you want to basically rip videos that are posted on Facebook, you will have to store the at the very least the link to that video on the 3rd party site (eg youtube). It would be possible to show videos from the logged in user's stream without any storage mechanism by using javascript or similar to query the user's stream with a filter.